# php if specific date expires do not echo vars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to NOT echo a var if the date has expired.

My PHP below shows:

Match 1 - April 1, 2015

Match 2 - April 8, 2015

So what I need is that, IF the Current date is, April 2, 2015, Match 1 will not echo. If April 30th, nothing will echo.

Here is the php

```
<?php
$match1 = "Match 1 - April 1, 2015";
$match2 = "Match 2 - April 8, 2015";
?>

<?=$match1?>
<?=$match2?>
```

I have looked at several codes and tried a few myself, but nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? You just need to grab the date from that string and see if it has past or not. No mystery to how to do this.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to check if the date as expired, i only seen an attempt to echo..

Comment: How about using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Comment: @JohnConde, thanks, but it is a mystery when you are learning PHP.

Comment: @NewToJS, I did not include what I tried, because it did not work and I did not want to put anything in the question that would confuse future users. Turns out nothing I did anything like the answer anyways.

Comment: @kidA, thanks. I started looking into that and trying it when Dish_Rex provided his answer. His turned out much better than what I was trying with it. But it was in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea:

```
$expiration_date = strtotime("2 April 2015"); //converts your date into a unix timestamp

$time = time(); //current time in unix format

if ($time < $expiration_date){ // if the current time is less than expiration date do something
    echo $match1; // or whatever variable you wanted to echo 
} // if the current time is past the expiration date the if statement will evaluate to false and do nothing
```

Comment: thanks @Dish, instead of echo, how can I make it use the include '$match1'; so that it will use the <?=$match1?> on the page

Comment: I am a little confused at your question and what you actually want. In your above code your $match1 and $match2 are string variables. You use include statements when you want to include another file in the current file.   example: `<?php include ("theFileName.php");`. You will have to explain more.

Comment: I want to be able to echo the $match1 more than once on the page, so without having to place the entire php code into the page again, I can just echo the $match1 in 4 or 5 places and then when the IF $time is Less than statement would work on all of them

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you want. However, there isn't really a way to do that. If you want to use $match1 in multiple places throughout the page but only if a certain condition is met then you will need to check it each time: `if ($time < $expiration_date){echo $match1; }`. Or the only other way I can think of is `if ($time < $expiration_date){$match1 = 'Match 1 - April 1, 2015'; } else {$match1 = '';}` This way throughout the page $match1 will be either 'Match 1 - April 1, 2015' or '' depending on what the date is.

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured that out as well after playing with it. Thanks again for all your help and responses!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this for future users.

If you are wanting to have a specific div show/hide depending on an expiration date, you can create the div's on a seperate PHP page and then include them with your php as follows:

**Include.php**

```
<?php if (time() < strtotime("1 January 2016")){include('Div1.php');}?>
```

**Div1.php**

```
<div class="myclass">I want this Div included with Include.php if it is not expired past January 1 2016</div>
```

Thought it may be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another PHP code for those that want to show a certain div for a certain date period and then default to another div if it is not at that date.

For example, I am using this for a website that prepares taxes (USA).

Tax season starts Jan 1st and ends April 15th. The client needed to show a certain div during tax season showing they prepare taxes, off season, they help with accounting software setup.

**Note - notice the end date is 1 day past 04/15 this is due to you having to add +1 day to your end date to make sure your end date is still active to show.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if ((time() > strtotime("01/01/2015")) && (time() < strtotime("04/16/2015")))
    {include "seasonON.php";}else{include "seasonOFF.php";}
?>
```

**seasonON.php**

```
<div>YES, Tax season is here and we prepare Taxes!</div>
```

**seasonOFF.php**

```
<div>Tax season is over, but we can help you with your accounting software</div>
```